# Accessing image files

Tags: html, mysql, django

I'm working in a project which I have a directory with 10k images, and I want display those images, with a search in my website. So, the user can choose the image he wants through the search, access the image, and download it. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name of images must be the same as saved in the image directory, after that when the user clicks to download the image it will return the name of the image.

e.g. base_path = 'E:/images/

image_name = request_nme + '.jpg'

```
file_path = os.path.join(base_path, image_name)
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(fh, content_type='application/jpg')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know a good way to get the names of the image files, from the directory with the 10k images, and create the database?

Comment: do this..

pathofImage = 'e:/images/'
getListofImages = os.listdir(pathofImage)

and pass this variable to the table. @Marcelo

Comment: clone this project and run it, it will help you to understand
https://github.com/UmairLakhani/downloadImages