# Django download files

Tags: python, django, url

I'm working in a project which I want display many images in a website, so the user can download them. I can display the name of the images, but the download isn't working. I think it's something on my views, because I'm using Django, and getting the error `the current path ... didn't match any of this`. The name of the directory with the images is `Images`, and has others sub directories inside, and inside those sub directories, there are the images.

My views page, I think the problem is here, in the download function:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.http import FileResponse

def index(request):
    flPath = os.listdir('Images/')
    fl4 = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Images/", topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            fl4.append(os.path.join(root, name))
        for name in dirs:
            fl4.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return render(request, 'catalog/index.html', {'path': fl4})

def downloadImage(request, path):
    imagePath = 'Images/'
    file_path = os.path.join(imagePath, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + file_path
            return response
    raise Http404
```

My app urls, catalog.urls:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('Images/<str:path>', downloadImage, name='download'),
]
```

My project urls, SiteSmu4Img:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Images/', include('catalog.urls')),
    path('', include('catalog.urls')),
]
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if path %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Images</th>
            <th>Download</th>
        </tr>
        {% for i in path %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ i }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ i }}">download</a></td>
            </tr>
        <img src="Images/{{ i }}">
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

The stack trace:

```
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3508
Not Found: /Images/Images/Images/fisc/LOGO NOVA.png
Not Found: /Images/Images/Images/leg/Niterói.jpg
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:39] "GET /Images/Images/Images/fisc/LOGO%20NOVA.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2787
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:39] "GET /Images/Images/Images/leg/Niter%C3%B3i.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2783
Not Found: /Images/Images/Images/leg/thumb_drone_site@2x.png
Not Found: /Images/Images/Images/urb/teste/1461270191180.jpg
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:39] "GET /Images/Images/Images/leg/thumb_drone_site@2x.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2812
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:39] "GET /Images/Images/Images/urb/teste/1461270191180.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2812
Not Found: /Images/Images/Images/urb/teste/1461270191336.jpg
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:39] "GET /Images/Images/Images/urb/teste/1461270191336.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2812
Not Found: /Images/Images/Images/urb/teste/1461270202199.jpg
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:39] "GET /Images/Images/Images/urb/teste/1461270202199.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2812
Not Found: /Images/Images/Images/urb/teste
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:39] "GET /Images/Images/Images/urb/teste HTTP/1.1" 404 2758
Internal Server Error: /Images/Images/Images/urb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documentos\SiteSmu4_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Documentos\SiteSmu4_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Documentos\SiteSmu4_env\SiteSmu4Img\catalog\views.py", line 20, in downloadImage
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Images/urb'
Internal Server Error: /Images/Images/Images/fisc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documentos\SiteSmu4_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Documentos\SiteSmu4_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Documentos\SiteSmu4_env\SiteSmu4Img\catalog\views.py", line 20, in downloadImage
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Images/fisc'
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:40] "GET /Images/Images/Images/urb HTTP/1.1" 500 66812
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:40] "GET /Images/Images/Images/fisc HTTP/1.1" 500 66828
Not Found: /Images/Images/Images/urb/1461270202199.jpg
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:40] "GET /Images/Images/Images/urb/1461270202199.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2794
Internal Server Error: /Images/Images/Images/leg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documentos\SiteSmu4_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Documentos\SiteSmu4_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Documentos\SiteSmu4_env\SiteSmu4Img\catalog\views.py", line 20, in downloadImage
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Images/leg'
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:40] "GET /Images/Images/Images/leg HTTP/1.1" 500 66812
Not Found: /Images/Images/Images/urb/LOGOFOOTER@2x.jpg
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:40] "GET /Images/Images/Images/urb/LOGOFOOTER@2x.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2794
Not Found: /Images/Images/Images/urb/x22323604_NI-Niteroi-RJ-26-05-2010Acessibilidade-em-Niteroi-Deficientes-fi.jpg.pagespeed.ic.KEumjIi-TY.jpg
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:40] "GET /Images/Images/Images/urb/x22323604_NI-Niteroi-RJ-26-05-2010Acessibilidade-em-Niteroi-Deficientes-fi.jpg.pagespeed.ic.KEumjIi-TY.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3061
Not Found: /Images/leg/thumb_drone_site@2x.png
[03/Nov/2020 17:11:43] "GET /Images/leg/thumb_drone_site@2x.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2770
```

Comment: Can you include the actual stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

The issue in you code is:
catalog.urls: `path('Images/', include('catalog.urls')),`

SiteSmu4Img: `path('Images/<str:path>', downloadImage, name='download'),`

so, in total the path should be like `Images/Images/<str:path>`,
but in the template you have just:
`<img src="Images/{{ i }}">`

Correct this issue first, then show the stacktrace if the solution won't fix all the errors.

Add another `Images` into the template for the beginning and add the leading slash in the path:

`<img src="/Images/Images/{{ i }}">`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I still can't download the images. And I put the stack trace in the question.

Answer (score -1):

you can't get images or any static file directly.

Django finds resources of the static folder or media folder.

add images in static folder and add `STATIC_FOLDER`, `STATIC_URL` values in settings.py

if you want to add images through the website, set `MEDIA_ROOT`, `MEDIA_URL` in `settings.py`

add a URL in `urls.py`. now you can access images through Django.

[get Media files Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root)

Comment: Django has an alternative ways to serve static files. The topicstarter uses one of them. It is not the best way to serve static files in Django but technically it is possible.

Comment: Yes, as @artembo pointed, you can. Look that question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972909/accessing-image-files/63973049?noredirect=1#comment113136515_63973049